# [PHP/HTML]: URL Masking

Tags: php, html

I want to know about the advantages and disadvantages of URL masking. Does it really make sense from security point of view?

Comment: a little vague. there are several different ways to "URL" mask : client side (iframe/JS) httpd server (redirect/rewrites), or http proxy.  maybe describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lance: I just wanted to know whether masking serves any real purpose or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security point of view you are using the [security trough obscurity](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) principle which by itself is not safe at all.

The only 'safety' aspect you are going to get is that users are more unlikely to tamper with the URL.